# Form not passing data to php file while using bootstrap

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, post, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to create a modal that will allow a user to enter some data and then have php send an email with this data.
I have a form in the modal and the php sends the email however I cannot seem to get/use the data within the form as it doesn't seem to recover anything when I use the $_POST. Can someone please help as this is driving me mad.
Code is listed below

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalform" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
 aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" 
               data-dismiss="modal">
                   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                   <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                Submit your details to have a Sales Assistant call you back
            </h4>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal Body -->
        <div class="modal-body">

            <form role="form" method="post" action="enquire.php">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="InputName">Your Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control"
                  id="InputName" placeholder="Your Name"/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="InputCar">Car Type</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control"
                      id="InputCar" placeholder="Car you are interested in"/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="InputContact">Phone Number</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control"
                      id="InputContact" placeholder="A number for us to contact you on"/>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>


        </div>

        <!-- Modal Footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <h4>Alternatively you can call us on </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

php

```
<?php


    $InputName = $_POST['InputName'];
    $InputCar = $_POST['InputCar'];
    $InputContact = $_POST['InputContact'];
    $from = "made up email address";
    $to = "another made up email address";
    $subject = "Enquiry from web page";

    $message = "$InputName is interested in $InputCar. Contact them on $InputContact";

    $headers = "From: $from \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $from \r\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $from\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 


if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) 
{
    echo "Mail sent OK";
} 
else 
{
    echo "Error sending email!";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your forms were all wrong.. This is how the form should be.

```
 <form action="" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Your Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Car Type</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="car" placeholder="Car you are interested in">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Phone Number</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="A number for us to contact you on">
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="submit" name="send">
                </form>
```

Your PHP should then be:

```
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {

    $InputName = $_POST['name'];
    $InputCar = $_POST['car'];
    $InputContact = $_POST['phone'];

    // do code
}
```

EDIT: under form action="" you need to add your PHP file again.

Comment: Thanks, that has solved the problem perfectly. I was so focused on the problem being with POST that I never thought to check the form was properly constructed.

Comment: No issue at all. When it comes to forms you need to ensure each form input has a name=" " tag as this is how it'll trigger the PHP and take the input from the form fields. You are partially correct on the POST issue though as you never have an `if (isset($_POST['name'])` which is basically where it's stating if you have pressed the submit button do this (which needs to be the very first thing you do before anymore PHP).